# Почему не работает onmessage при получении ответа с сервера (websocket)?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

Написал сервер для работы по ws и пытаюсь проверить его. Конектиться нормально, сообщения отправляются с клиента тоже нормально, но вот метод onmessage не срабатывает при получении сообщения с сервера. В чем проблема не понимаю, нужна помощь.

JS:

```
      var btnSend = document.getElementById('btn_send');
      btnSend.addEventListener('click', sendMessage, false);

      var btnDisconnect = document.getElementById('btn_disconnect');
      btnDisconnect.addEventListener('click', disconnect, false);

      let uri = 'ws://localhost:8080/websocket_chat/websocket_chat/Bibus';
      var webSocket = new WebSocket(uri);

      webSocket.onopen = function(){
        console.info('connected with websocket!');
      }

      webSocket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.info('before parse json in onmessage')
        let message = JSON.parse(event.data);
        console.info('after parse json in onmessage')

        if(message.type == 'MESSAGE') {
          updateChatArea(message);
        }
      }

      function updateChatArea(message) {
        let from = message.from + "</br>";
        let align  = "";
        let margin = "";

          
        align = "text-align:right";
        margin = 'margin:0px 0px 0px 130px;';

        let style = 'width:320px;' + margin + align;
            
        let p = document.createElement("p");
        p.setAttribute('style', style);
            
        p.innerHTML = from + message.content;

        chatArea.appendChild(p);
      }

      function sendMessage() {
        console.info('send message')
        let message = {
          from : 'Bibus',
          type : 'MESSAGE',
          content : 'privet'
        };

        let msgJSON = JSON.stringify(message);
        webSocket.send(msgJSON);
      }

      function disconnect() {
        webSocket.close();
        console.info('disconnect with websocket!');
      }
```

Java:
EndPoint:

```
@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket_chat/{username}",
        decoders = WebSocketMessageDecoder.class,
        encoders = WebSocketMessageEncoder.class)
class ChatEndpoint {
    private Map<Session, String> users = new HashMap<>();

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session, @PathParam("username")String username) throws IOException {
        if(!users.containsValue(username)) {
            users.put(session, username);

            session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(new WebsocketMessage(MessageType.CONNECTION, true, "Congratulate, good connection!"));

            generalSending(new WebsocketMessage(MessageType.USER_LIST, (Set<String>) users.values()));
        } else {
            session.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(new WebsocketMessage(MessageType.CONNECTION, false, "This username is already exist!"));
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(Session session, WebsocketMessage message) throws IOException {
        generalSending(message);
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) throws IOException {
        users.remove(session);

        generalSending(new WebsocketMessage(MessageType.USER_LIST, (Set<String>) users.values()));
    }

    @OnError
    public void onError(Session session, Throwable throwable) {
        // Do error handling here
    }

    private void generalSending(WebsocketMessage message) {
        synchronized (users) {
            for (Session userSession : users.keySet()) {
                userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendObject(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MessageType:

```
public enum MessageType {
    MESSAGE, USER_LIST, CONNECTION
}
```

WebsocketMessage:

```
@Data
public class WebsocketMessage {
    private MessageType type;
    private String from;
    private Set<String> userList;
    private String content;
    private boolean resultConnectStatus;

    public WebsocketMessage(MessageType type, boolean resultConnectStatus, String content) {
        this.type = type;
        this.content = content;
        this.resultConnectStatus = resultConnectStatus;
    }

    public WebsocketMessage(MessageType type, String from, String content) {
        this.type = type;
        this.from = from;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public WebsocketMessage(MessageType type, Set<String> userList) {
        this.type = type;
        this.userList = userList;
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Где онмесседж не срабатывает на сервере?

Comment: На сервере срабатывает нормально, судя по панели инструментов, на скрине

Comment: На панели инструментов только http-заголовок.

Comment: а где ты отправляешь сообщение?

Comment: со странице, через кнопку отправить,                                                                                      
        'function sendMessage() {
        console.info('send message')
        let message = {
          from : 'Bibus',
          type : 'MESSAGE',
          content : 'privet'
        };

        let msgJSON = JSON.stringify(message);
        webSocket.send(msgJSON);
      }'

Comment: на сервере, а не на клиенте - отправка сообщения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто принимал участие, как многие подметили, да, были проблем на стороне сервера(хотя я усердно не хотел это принимать)). В общем суть проблемы была в том что класс конечной точки был не публичный, в связи с чем выскакивало исключение в логах glasfish (да, я залез туда только сейчас):

```
[2022-12-07T09:20:58.409-0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint] [tid: _ThreadID=23 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(5)] [timeMillis: 1670415658409] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Exception thrown from onError method 'private void endpoint.ChatEndpoint.onError(javax.websocket.Session,java.lang.Throwable)'
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint can not access a member of class endpoint.ChatEndpoint with modifiers "private"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:95)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:594)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.callMethod(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:431)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.onError(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:455)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.callMethod(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:434)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint.access$100(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.AnnotatedEndpoint$WholeHandler$1.onMessage(AnnotatedEndpoint.java:518)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.SessionImpl.notifyMessageHandlers(SessionImpl.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.core.EndpointWrapper.onMessage(EndpointWrapper.java:495)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.server.TyrusEndpoint.onMessage(TyrusEndpoint.java:174)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.websockets.DefaultWebSocket.onMessage(DefaultWebSocket.java:156)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.websockets.frametypes.TextFrameType.respond(TextFrameType.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.websockets.DataFrame.respond(DataFrame.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.onDataAvailable(TyrusHttpUpgradeHandler.java:113)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.processDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:488)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer$ReadHandlerImpl.onDataAvailable(InputBuffer.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.append(InputBuffer.java:855)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:222)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
]]
```

Ещё раз всем спасибо.

Comment: удалось запустить весь цикл? для нескольких обращений?

Comment: да, сообщения отправляются - приходят, но при подключении участники как будто изолированы друг от друга, возможно проблема в обозначении конечной точки

Comment: В общем я забыл что для каждого коннекта делается свой поток, а, следовательно, нужно сделать мапу с сессиями статичной

Comment: В смысле почту?

Comment: не нахожу письмо

Answer (score 0):

но если по-нормальному, то такое сообщение от клиента

```
let message = {
      from : 'Bibus',
      type : 'MESSAGE',
      content : 'privet'
    };
```

не рационально, **from** лишнее, т.к. источник определяется однозначно по сессии сообщения, которая однозначно привязывается к регистрации пользователя при его регистрации/авторизации. **type** - лишнее, потому как всё , что идет от клиента есть "сообщение" , **content** - лишнее потому, что и так будет понятно...
достаточно  разделить сообщение и содержание любым ( к примеру непечатаемым )символом. при коротких сообщениях при наличии from, type, content "кпд" передачи очень маленький.
тип "сообщение" логичнее трактовать как "команда". т.е. команда- (по терминалогии с сервером java - метод) метод, который будет обрабатывать это сообщение. таких "команд" на странице может быть море, и для обработки их можно использовать if или case, можно -но совершенно не нужно, намного эффективнее использовать рефлексию, это будет намного быстрее, компактнее...
проверено,  желающие поспорить, узнать подробности - прошу к диалогу.

Comment: само собой я это учту, но код в js тестовый, я хочу на данном этапе добиться получения сообщения в методе onmessage с сервера, при отправке с клиента. Ещё в postman пытался отправить, при отправке так же получается ответ с сервера.

Comment: есть такой метод, как пошаговая отладка, точки остановки. где ты видишь, что на сервер пришло что-то? самое простое systemout в интересных местах кода.

Comment: Как я понял в инструментах браузера во вкладке ответы это ответы от сервера, разве нет?

Comment: а ты уверен, что сообщение приходят на сервер?

Comment: я был уверен, так как коннект происходил нормально, но честно говоря я уже не уверен